# UWP Same Thumb Style but looks different

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I used the same style for the `Thumb` of the slider, but the Thumb looks different in different context.

Expected Pressed Thumb:

[image: Expected Normal Thumb]

Expected Pressed Thumb:

[image: Expected Pressed Thumb]

Real Normal Thumb:

[image: Real Normal Thumb]

Real Pressed Thumb

[image: Real Pressed Thumb]

As you can see from the real ones, they are somewhat transparent in the middle. Why are they different from the expected ones? How can I make them behave like the expected ones? They share the same code.

These are the styles:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse
                    x:Name="ellipse"
                    Fill="{StaticResource MediaSliderThumbFillBrush}"
                    Stroke="White"
                    StrokeThickness="3.2" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style
    x:Key="SliderPressedThumbStyle"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
    TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse
                    x:Name="ellipse"
                    Fill="White"
                    Stroke="White"
                    StrokeThickness="3.2" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style
    x:Key="SliderPointerOverThumbStyle"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
    TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse
                    x:Name="ellipse"
                    Fill="{StaticResource MediaSliderThumbFillBrush}"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource MedialSliderPointerOverThumbStrokeBrush}"
                    StrokeThickness="3.2" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

These are the brushes:

```
<media:BackdropBlurBrush x:Key="MediaSliderThumbFillBrush" Amount="50" />
<AcrylicBrush
    x:Key="MediaSliderTrackRectBrush"
    BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
    FallbackColor="White"
    TintColor="White"
    TintOpacity="0.25" />
<AcrylicBrush
    x:Key="MedialSliderPointerOverThumbStrokeBrush"
    BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
    FallbackColor="White"
    TintColor="White"
    TintOpacity="0.75" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UWP Same Thumb Style but looks different

Please check [`MediaControl.xaml`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/MediaControl.xaml#L273) custom control.  You set the Opacity as 0.75 for `FullMediaControlGrid` grid cause this issue, you could solve this by setting Opacity  as 1.0.

```
<Grid
    x:Name="FullMediaControlGrid"
    Background="{x:Bind Background}"
    Opacity="1"
    RequestedTheme="Dark"
    Visibility="Visible">
```

Comment: Thank you! I never know this would cause that. And today should be holiday, why are you still working? Haha.